# Symfony form framework - change value before edit

Tags: forms, symfony1

In which function can I change the value of a field before it gets displayed in the form ?

I'm having a weird bug with tinyMce ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990104/input-code-in-tinymce/5574636)), and I would like to do htmlentities() to the contents before it gets displayed in a textarea.

Where do I modify the value of a field before it gets displayed in the form ?

**EDIT**

This works, but it seems to strip any html it doesn't understand :(

```
$this->content = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
$this->content->setContents(htmlentities($this->content->getContents(),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$this->form = $this->configuration->getForm($this->content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works :

```
$this->content = $this->getRoute()->getObject();

$this->content->setContents(htmlentities($this->content->getContents(),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));

$this->form = $this->configuration->getForm($this->content);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be working if the escaping_strategy = true. Check this http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_escaping_method
Also you can check this [How to allow certain HTML tags in a form field in Symfony 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320524/how-to-allow-certain-html-tags-in-a-form-field-in-symfony-1-2)
Otherwise you could try to do htmlentities directly on the template